# How to apply a metaclass to all my class without hardcoding it in the class declaration

Tags: python-3.x

for an exam the professor ask me to write a metaclass that take effect on all the class in the project without declaring it directly in the class declaration, is that possible? how?
For example i have the following code:

```
class MetaOne(type): 
    def __new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict):
        print('In MetaOne.new: ', classname, supers, classdict, sep='\n...') 
        return type.__new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict) 
    def __init__(Class, classname, supers, classdict): 
        print('In MetaOne init:', classname, supers, classdict, sep='\n...') 
        print('...init class object:', list(Class.__dict__.keys()))

class Eggs: pass 

print('making class') 

class Spam(Eggs): 
    data = 1 
    def meth(self, arg): pass 

print('making instance') 
X = Spam() 
print('data:', X.data)
```

And i want that the output is equal to the output of the following code:

```
class MetaOne(type): 
    def __new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict):
        print('In MetaOne.new: ', classname, supers, classdict, sep='\n...') 
        return type.__new__(meta, classname, supers, classdict) 
    def __init__(Class, classname, supers, classdict): 
        print('In MetaOne init:', classname, supers, classdict, sep='\n...') 
        print('...init class object:', list(Class.__dict__.keys()))

class Eggs: pass 

print('making class') 

class Spam(Eggs, metaclass=MetaOne): 
    data = 1 
    def meth(self, arg): pass 

print('making instance') 
X = Spam() 
print('data:', X.data)
```

The metaclass as to be applied to all my class even if i don't declare it directly.
I had red a lot of question about metaclasses, but at the end all use always the metaclass=meta declaration in he definition of their class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is very difficult for me to understand your question.

If `Eggs` inherits `MetaOne` and `Spam` inherits `Eggs`, does this accomplish what you are trying to do?

#### Example #1:

```
class MetaOne(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass

class Eggs(MetaOne):
    pass

class Spam(Eggs):
    pass
```

#### Example #2:

Perhaps the information available at [lgiordani.com](http://lgiordani.com/blog/2014/10/14/decorators-and-metaclasses/) will be of use to you, especially the following code block from the preceding link:

```
class FilterClass(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(name, bases, **kwds):
        return collections.OrderedDict()

    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds):
        result = type.__new__(metacls, name, bases, dict(namespace))
        result._filters = [
            value for value in namespace.values() if hasattr(value, '_filter')]
        return result
```

This block of code demonstrates how to create a metaclass without using `metaclass=ABCMeta`.

#### Example #3:

Are you familiar with `super()`?

```
class MetaOne:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Eggs: pass

class Spam(MetaOne, Eggs):
    def __init__(self, name, is_tasty):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.is_tasty = is_tasty

>>> s = Spam('meta', True)
>>> s
<__main__.Spam object at 0x100705b38>
>>> s.name
'meta'
>>> s.is_tasty
True
```

Though using `super()` isn't really metaclass

#### Example #4:

Depending on your version of Python, you may be able to define `__metaclass__ = MetaOne` at the module level, which would affect ALL classes below that declaration.

```
class MetaOne: pass

class Eggs: pass

__metaclass__ = MetaOne

class Spam: pass
class Scrambled: pass
class Fried: pass
```

In this use case, the metaclass of `Spam`, `Scrambled` and `Fried` would all be `MetaOne`.

Comment: Eggs doesn't  inherits MetaOne

Comment: Yes, in your code it does not. If it *were* to, `Spam` would need only inherit `Eggs`

Comment: That problem is to make the metaclass work without writing metaclass=ABCMeta in the class declaration

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer is beautiful, now I tried to resolve my exam and then I let you know which method i have used.

Answer (score 2):

**You can write `__metaclass__ = your_metaclass` at a module level**. All classes defined below will use that **metaclass**. You can overwrite this if you write `__metaclass__ = type` again in the class definiton. Child class are using the metaclass of the parent.